# Change product slug of a WooCommerce product - WPML

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, wpml

I am using **WPML** and I want to change the slug of my product . basically I want to keep same slug for a product for all languages.When ever I change it , slug gets assigned with appended `-en` or `-no` as per language. I dont want this -en to get appended.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

check this URL please hope you will get some solution

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-can-i-change-product-and-shop-url-slug/